# Tensorflow: assemble tiles into mosaic image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a tensor with shape (64, 32, 32, 1) which represents 64 32x32 grayscale tiles (patches). I need to restore a full 8x8 tiles image by combining the tiles together into a 256x256 pixel square image. What is the best way to do it? Seems like there should be some simple combination of transposing / reshaping or something, but can't quite wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tile_size = 32
mosaic_size = 8
pic_size = tile_size * mosaic_size

res = tf.reshape(tiles, [mosaic_size, mosaic_size, tile_size, tile_size, 1])
res = tf.transpose(res, [0, 2, 1, 3, 4])
res = tf.reshape(res, (pic_size, pic_size, 1))
```